# I am getting confuse in Pandas DataFrame creation

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

```
names = ['Name', 'Score', 'State']
df = pd.DataFrame([{'Sam', 19, 'Tamil Naidu'},
                 {'Kari', 10, 'Himachal Pradesh'},
                 {'Sam', 19, 'Tamil Naidu'},
                  {'Samual Dan', 11, 'Haryana'}], columns = names)
```

I am getting incorrect output. Can anyone explain the reason and what can be done?

I tried to create a DF and then I am getting the output shown in the image. When I am changing the name of the states into abbreviation it is getting placed in correct position and if I am writing in full or increasing the length of the name it is getting into wrong column. I am confused what actually is the concept behind it and why this is happening.

Comment: What is the expected output? We can't see anything

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're using a list of **sets** as input, but sets are **unordered**.

You most likely should use a list of **lists**:

```
names = ['Name', 'Score', 'State']
df = pd.DataFrame([['Sam', 19, 'Tamil Naidu'],
                   ['Kari', 10, 'Himachal Pradesh'],
                   ['Sam', 19, 'Tamil Naidu'],
                   ['Samual Dan', 11, 'Haryana']],
                  columns=names)
```

Output:

```
         Name  Score             State
0         Sam     19       Tamil Naidu
1        Kari     10  Himachal Pradesh
2         Sam     19       Tamil Naidu
3  Samual Dan     11           Haryana
```

Answer (score 0):

A list containing sets can't be directly converted into dataframe. The requirement of converting into dataframe is:
the input should be:

1. Either two dimensional `list`
2. Or a `dict` in which the values of each key of the `dict` should be a list

So, in your present scenario, each `set` inside the `list` can be converted into `sublists`. But the problem lies here is: while changing from set to list, the order of the elements changes.

So, the idea here is:

Step-1. All the sets inside the list should be converted into lists

Step-2. Using logical criteria, the order of the elements inside the sublists is brought back to the original order.

Step-3. Convert into dataframe

Let us do it now:

```
import pandas as pd
names = ['Name', 'Score', 'State']
lst = [{'Sam', 19, 'Tamil Naidu'},
                 {'Kari', 10, 'Himachal Pradesh'},
                 {'Sam', 19, 'Tamil Naidu'},
                  {'Samual Dan', 11, 'Haryana'}]
States = 'Tamil Naidu', 'Himachal Pradesh', 'Haryana'

#convert sets inside lst into lists
lst = [list(x) for x in lst]

#create an empty 2-dimensional list with required length
new_lst = [['a' for x in range(3)] for y in range(4)]


#Iterate over lst and in turn iterate over sublist of lst
for i,x in enumerate(lst):
    for j, y in enumerate(x):

        #If the element is integer, make it as second element
        if isinstance(y, int):
            new_lst[i][1] = y
        
        #if the element found in tuple of States make it as 3rd element
        elif y in States:
            new_lst[i][2] = y
        

        #if the above 2 criteria are not met, make as first element
        else:
            new_lst[i][0] = y

#Now convert into dataframe
df = pd.DataFrame(new_lst, columns = names)
print(df)

'''Output:
         Name  Score             State
0         Sam     19       Tamil Naidu
1        Kari     10  Himachal Pradesh
2         Sam     19       Tamil Naidu
3  Samual Dan     11           Haryana
'''
```